# Centering components inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a black jack game and I need little bit of help with the layouts of the components. The layout looks like this atm. Do not mind the colors. They are just there becuase I want to be able to distinguish the different components:

[image]

I'm trying to create "cards" in the middle of the blue JPanels. "Spader 4" and "Spader 3" are supposed to be spawning next to each other in the middle and they are supposed to have a border. How can I achieve this.

```
    public KortlekSwing(){

    //Startar kortspelet
    kortlek.blandaKortlek();

    String playerKortEttText = drawCard(kortlek.Kortlek, playerScore);
    JLabel playerKortEtt = new JLabel(playerKortEttText);
    playerKortEtt.setSize(80, 45);
    playerKortEtt.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    if(red){
        playerKortEtt.setForeground(Color.RED);
    } else {
        playerKortEtt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    String playerKortTvåText = drawCard(kortlek.Kortlek, playerScore);
    JLabel playerKortTvå = new JLabel(playerKortTvåText);
    playerKortTvå.setSize(80, 45);
    playerKortTvå.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    playerKortTvå.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    if(red){
        playerKortTvå.setForeground(Color.RED);
    } else {
        playerKortTvå.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    String computerKortEttText = drawCard(kortlek.Kortlek, computerScore);
    String computerKortTvåText = drawCard(kortlek.Kortlek, playerScore);

    JLabel computerKortEtt = new JLabel(computerKortEttText);
    JLabel computerKortTvå = new JLabel(computerKortTvåText);

    frame = new JPanel();
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    PlayerPanel = new JPanel();
    PlayerCardsPanel = new JPanel();
    PlayerButtons = new JPanel();

    ComputerPanel = new JPanel();
    ComputerCardsPanel = new JPanel();
    ComputerButtons = new JPanel();

    PlayerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    PlayerCardsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    ComputerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ComputerCardsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    PlayerPanel.setSize(475, 120);
    PlayerCardsPanel.setSize(460, 120);
    PlayerButtons.setSize(460, 140);
    PlayerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    PlayerCardsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    PlayerButtons.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    ComputerPanel.setSize(475, 120);
    ComputerCardsPanel.setSize(460, 120);
    ComputerButtons.setSize(460, 140);
    ComputerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    ComputerCardsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    ComputerButtons.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    PlayerCardsPanel.add(playerKortEtt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    PlayerCardsPanel.add(playerKortTvå, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    PlayerButtons.add(PlayerKortButton);
    PlayerButtons.add(PlayerPassButton);

    ComputerButtons.add(ComputerKortButton);
    ComputerButtons.add(ComputerPassButton);
    ComputerButtons.add(NyttSpelButton);
    ComputerButtons.add(ExitButton);

    PlayerText.setOpaque(false);
    PlayerPanel.add(PlayerText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    PlayerPanel.add(PlayerCardsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    PlayerPanel.add(PlayerButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    ComputerText.setOpaque(false);
    ComputerPanel.add(ComputerText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ComputerPanel.add(ComputerCardsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ComputerPanel.add(ComputerButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    ComputerPanel.setSize(475, 190);
    ComputerCardsPanel.setSize(460, 120);
    ComputerButtons.setSize(460, 100);

    NyttSpelButton.addActionListener(new NyttSpel());

    frame.add(PlayerPanel);
    frame.add(ComputerPanel);

    add(frame);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `setSize` on components, these values will generally be ignored and updated by the layout managers as they see fit.

Secondly, instead of using using a `BorderLayout` on the `ComputerCardsPanel` and `PlayerCardsPanel`, which seems to be where the cards are to be displayed, you could trying using a `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout` instead

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more ideas